# Is there a way to delete spells?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I remember in past Elder Scrolls games, you could delete spells from your inventory. I don't think this is possible in Skyrim, but it would be nice to be able to remove lower-level/obsolete spells to declutter your inventory.

Who needs Healing or Close Wounds when I have Grand Healing now?

Comment: I don't know of any way to delete spells, but at least there is a finite number of spells (unlike previous Elder Scrolls).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no in-game way of removing learned spells, but if you're playing on PC you can use the [Spell Eraser mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/18096).

> Adds a power that removes spells from your character.
>
> Some spells become obsolete as part of your character's progression. It's by design. It helps, then, to have a tool to remove these clutter spells from your magic menu when you no longer need them. Spell Eraser is such a tool. It also helps with leftover spells like "Arniel's Convection" after their quests are over.
>
> Equip the Remove Spell power and the spell you want to remove, then just cast the power and hey presto! The spell is gone. You can also remove two spells at a time by equipping one in each hand. Note that some spells (like your starting Flames and Healing) cannot be removed.

Comment: Aw okay that's what I thought

Comment: The mod [Spell Amnesia](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3090606) is available on the XBox One which has a similar effect.

Answer (score -1):

`player.removespell [spell id]`

You should google the spell id.

Comment: That doesn't work. See [this Q&A](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/176690/player-removespell-console-command-not-working).