# 'player.removespell' console command not working

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to delete the "highborn" powers from a High Elf character (don't ask why, it's for... reasons). I can delete the active 50 point magicka boost with:`player.removespell 00105f16` but when I try to delete the regeneration power with: `player.removespell 000e40c8`, the console tells me: "*Spell 'Highborn' not found in player*". Furthermore, I can't delete any spells like flames or healing. I just get "*Spell 'whatever' not found in player"*. What's my problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you can't remove spells or powers that your character starts the game with via the console. However, people have made mods that allow you to remove them:

- [Power Eraser](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/34754/?) (for Highborn)
- [No Starting Spells](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/40410/?) (for Flames and Healing)

Answer (score 0):

You should type in "help highborn" and see what results you get. Navigate using Page Up and Down, and look for the spell, shout, or power, depending on what you want to remove. Try it again with the code that's listed there. If that doesn't help, research the spell via Google or so, and see what ID's are listed there.